# Error 416 Request Range Not Satisfiable while installing packages through Software Center / apt

Tags: networking, software-installation, software-center

I have a problem with the installation of packages through Ubuntu Software Center, or, in general, through apt.

I installed [CNTLM](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/cntlm.1.html) to configure the proxy authentication. I use that to connect to the network and I'm able to connect to the Internet through the Browser.

When I try to install some packages, Ubuntu Software Center and apt (if I use the terminal) return this error:

```
Failed to fetch *[URL]* 416 Request Range Not Satisfiable
```

What's that? How can I resolve the problem?

I tried to change the mirror from the sources.list but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

On the *„What's that?”* question the answer probably is that it is a [HTTP error message](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

> **10.4.17 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable**
>
> [...] a request included a Range request-header field [...], and
>   none of the range-specifier values in this field overlap the current
>   extent of the selected resource [...]

The HTTP request tried to retrieve a part of the file (specified as a range) but the file does not have data in that range. ([More on Content-Range.](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.16))

I suspect that the HTTP request was modified by the proxy in such a way that the server in question cannot accept.

Can you download a file in Firefox, pause the download and then resume it? Does it pick up where it left off or restarts the whole download?

Comment: Mmmh.. I'm sorry but is not the mozilla that actually download the file from the Internet: the server proxy I connect to download it and then i download the file from the local server. So I think this experiment could not be done. Any other idea? Thanks a lot anyway. :)